# where can i download opengl for windows vista

Tags: opengl, download

I've been searching and can't find the download files on opengl.org. can someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is just a standard. The implementations come with your graphics card drivers and are exposed using WGL extensions in Windows. There is a 'standard' implementation in the platform SDK that is accessed by including the OpenGL headers and the windows header, but this is a basic version (1.1 in XP. I think it's 1.4 in Vista).

If you want an easier method to gain access to all the features from your card's supported features and the basic set of features in the Windows standard OpenGL implementation then I'd suggest looking at GLEW (The openGL Extension Wrangler) which handles all the WGL calls to set up extensions for you.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL 1.1 header files are included in the Platform SDK. If you need to work with a more recent version this may help: [Moving Beyond OpenGL 1.1 for Windows](http://archive.gamedev.net/archive/reference/programming/features/oglext/)

Answer (score 1):

Windows (well, Visual Studio at least) comes with opengl, but only the older v1.1 - just

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <GL/gl.h> 
#include <GL/glu.h>
```

and link with opengl32.lib, and glu32.lib and you should be ok (its been a while, I may have missed a bit in there)